# Displaying a byte content given by an address

Tags: c, unix, pointers, char, byte

I have to display the content of n bytes starting in a specific memory address, i.e: an output for 25 bytes since 0x00004000 (segment text in virtual space) would be `#include <stdio.h> #inclu` (25 letters)

My idea was to assign to a `char *c` the address given, like: `*c=address;` and then `printf("%s",c);`. For me, conceptually makes sense and I know that in some cases it would cause a segmentation fault if the address is not valid.

However I have implemented it and it always causes a segmentation fault. I use `pmap <pid>` to know what areas can be displayed (low areas) of that process. When I say "areas that can be displayed" I mean text areas (code).

So, what I am doing wrong? is stupid the assignment `*c=address;` ?

Comment: You want `c=(char *)address`, not `*c=`. You want to assign to the pointer, not the object pointed to.

Comment: The assignment is valid, but probably that address doesn't contain a string (it needs to end with the char '\0'). By the way, have you tried running it with GDB / valgrind to show which access get you the segmentation fault? Are you sure you can access memory at that address?

Comment: @Marco It doesn’t matter what is at the address. It is never dereferenced, and the 0 termination is only relevant for string functions, typically those whose names start with `str`.

Comment: @ChristopherCreutzig he is using printf("%s", c); :P

Comment: @Marco He never assigns `address` to `c` (according to the description; having actual code would obviously be better), so that call will dereference `c` (my guess: an uninitialized value). – I see you just put that into your answer, too. +1!

Comment: @ChristopherCreutzig Yes, but even if he fixes that `printf("%s", c)` would still be wrong. It would either need to be `printf("%.25s", c)` or, more likely, a loop to print individual characters.

Comment: I understand that `*c=address` is not correct, it should be `c=address`, and it was stupid make `printf()` with `%s` if I want to display a char. In fact, my output still being garbage. My attempts always return illegible characters; any ideas? what else should I try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char *c = address;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    putchar(c[i]);
}
```

**Errors in your code**

having something like

```
char *c;
*c = address;
```

Is invalid, because c is a dangling pointer (you have never initialized it). You want to set the address which `c` *points to* to `address`: `c = address`

```
printf("%s",c);
```

You don't know if c is a proper string, it may contain garbage or may not be n bytes length. That's why I used `putchar`

Answer (score 1):

`*c = address` puts the value of `address` into the memory `c` *currently points to.* That is what the `*` is doing. To change where `c` points, use `c = address`.

But still, this sounds like a rather, ahem, suboptimal programming exercise.